# Как можно выделить текст в Selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Добрый день, подскажите как можно с помощью команд Selenium выделить слово на странице (как выделяем мышкой при копирование) и перейти к следующему ?

Comment: К чему следующему перейти?

Comment: К следующему слову

Comment: следующему найденному? Зачем переходить?

Comment: В сущности всё ради демонстрации. Алгоритм такой выделили то есть показали, перешли к другому слову повторили действие и так до конца страницы.

Comment: С помощью js можно прокручивать страницу.